# My Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate does not include timer in toolbox

Tags: timer, toolbox

I am making a windows 8 application and I need timer but there is no timer in toolbox. I'd be appreciated if you can help me solve this problem which I couldn't find the solution on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no timer for windows 8 applications. (Source: [Microsoft Dev Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/48b09080-e46a-4a40-977e-12b426369ff0/))

Link offers some solution of how to replace it. Maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my copy of Visual Basic Premium 2012, I also thought that there was no timer.  However, I found that in the **"Common Control Tab"**, all you need to do is click on the upper tab **"All Windows Forms"**.  There you will find the timer: just scroll down :)